# OmniMarkupPreviewer 404

Tags: sublimetext3

(English is not my native language)

Hello, I established [OmniMarkupPreviewer](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer). I open my page with Mediawiki markup and I press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `o` to see it in my browser. But the mistake opened:

```
Error: 404 Not Found

Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:51004/view/31' caused an error:

'buffer_id(31) is not valid (closed or unsupported file format)'

**NOTE:** If you run multiple instances of Sublime Text, you may want to adjust
the `server_port` option in order to get this plugin work again.
```

I tried to change «Settings - User» as advised [here](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer/issues/82#issuecomment-158705946):

```
{
    "server_host": "0.0.0.0",
    "server_port": 9998
}
```

But the new mistake turned out:

```
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:9998/view/52' caused an error:

'buffer_id(52) is not valid (closed or unsupported file format)'

**NOTE:** If you run multiple instances of Sublime Text, you may want to adjust
the `server_port` option in order to get this plugin work again.
```

What I need to make for the correct work of OmniMarkupPreviewer?

Comment: Xiongmin LIN's answer seems to work for me. If it solved your problem too, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there are two solutions in [here](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer/issues/85) by @scuml, i solved this problem by first solution: [Remove Strikethrough Extension]

Here is the answer:

Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > OmniMarkupPreviewer > Settings - User

paste the following to remove the strikeout package.

```
{
    "renderer_options-MarkdownRenderer": {
        "extensions": ["tables", "fenced_code", "codehilite"]
    }
}
```